Change table of contents font size
i am trying to standardise my indexes, and have some problems doing so.
My current main file
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

% for table entries
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2cm} % change length to suit
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Table }
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{:}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables

\section{Lorem}
\subsection{Ipsum}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
         &  \\
         & 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}

outputs this:

The font size of the "Contents" and "List of tables" is supposed to be the same as normal text, just bold. Also, the identation at the List of tables should match the identation of the other index, so it looks like this:

Can somebody help me here?

`\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\normalsize\bfseries}`
solves the first part. Its part of the tocloft package.

And \setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt} the last part.

After experimenting for an hour, i found the solution(s):
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\normalsize\bfseries}

This will change the font to normal size, bold.
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}

This on the other hand, will change the indentation.
:)


Glad you found a solution. Can you please change the title to your question that you want to change the font in the Table of Contents and NOT the index, they are different animals:)

Thank you for your comment, i changed the title, does it fit now?

Excellent thank you.
